# Values in braces in Spring Annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

This might be a simple question for those who know Spring, but since I am a newbie, I will ask it anyway.

I am going through some Spring code and I am not able to understand the following-

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{id}") 
 public void show(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {...}
```

The comment for this section of the code is - "When using URI Templates, access parameters using the @PathVariable annotation.

Now earlier, I came across code like

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/url/path") 
 public String list(Model model) {...}
```

By this, I understand that whenever the url "/url/path" is encountered, the list() method will be called, but I am not able to make sense of the former annotation. What does it mean?

Also, the next line says @PathVariable annotations can be limited via regular expressions

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
 public void show(@PathVariable("id:[\\d]*") String idl) {...} // will match only numberic IDs
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

> URI templates can be used for convenient access to selected parts of a URL in a `@RequestMapping` method.
>
> For example, the URI Template `http://www.example.com/users/{userId}` contains the variable `userId`. Assigning the value `fred` to the variable yields `http://www.example.com/users/fred`.
>
> In Spring MVC you can use the `@PathVariable` annotation on a method argument to bind it to the value of a URI template variable:

So, in your example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}") 
public void show(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {...}
```

This will extract the part of the URL represented by `{id}`, and bind it to the `id` method parameter, e.g. the path `/42` will bind `42` to `id`.